# how can detect devices on my computer with electron desktop build app

Tags: printing, device, electron, modem, dial-up

how can we detect hardware connected to the device with electron framework.
For example imaging we want's to get the dial-up modem ready with electron and use that modem for sending fax whit it.

[I find this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-printer) for using printer's but how can use other devices :
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-printer`

Comment: Your question is too general, do you have a specific device in mind? Depending on the device the OS may already provide an API to access it, or the manufacturer of the device might provide an SDK that you would use to communicate with the device.

Comment: whatever device ... I want's to read some article about using device in my app with electron.

Comment: I'm experience some web development especially with nodejs  and do not word with any hardware device, i want's to read some good article about how to work with devices

Comment: In this question i want's to create an app to work with dial-up modem for sending faxes

Comment: I think you have to write your own. Eletron is still new and It has not covered all native functions of OS.